# How to use static variables in for loops to maintain a value across multiple loops in C

Tags: c, static

I am writing code to solve the mastermind puzzle with 4 colours and 4 pegs, this is an extract from the code that I am having issues with.  The problem I am having is that when the loop is executed again it starts from the values of num1,2,3,4 do not change and therefore I return "r,r,r,r" at the end of each loop. I am trying to use a static variable to fix this:

```
int  readOK = 0;
    while (readOK == 0)
    {
        static int  num1 = 0;
        static int  num2 = 0;
        static int  num3 = 0;
        static int  num4 = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (num1 = 0; num1 <= 3; num1++)
            for (num2 = 0; num2 <= 3; num2++)
                for (num3 = 0; num3 <= 3; num3++)
                    for (num4 = 0; num4 <= 3; num4++)
                    {
                        if (num1 == 0)
                        {
                            return 'r';
                        }
                        if (num1 == 1)
                        {
                            return 'g';
                        }
                        if (num1 == 2)
                        {
                            return 'b';
                        }
                        if (num1 == 3)
                        {
                            return 'y';
                        }

                        if (num2 == 0)
                        {
                            return 'r';
                        }
                        if (num2 == 1)
                        {
                            return 'g';
                        }
                        if (num2 == 2)
                        {
                            return 'b';
                        }
                        if (num2 == 3)
                        {
                            return 'y';
                        }

                        if (num3 == 0)
                        {
                            return 'r';
                        }
                        if (num3 == 1)
                        {
                            return 'g';
                        }
                        if (num3 == 2)
                        {
                            return 'b';
                        }
                        if (num3 == 3)
                        {
                            return 'y';
                        }

                        if (num4 == 0)
                        {
                            return 'r';
                        }
                        if (num4 == 1)
                        {
                            return 'g';
                        }
                        if (num4 == 2)
                        {
                            return 'b';
                        }
                        if (num4 == 3)
                        {
                            return 'y';
                        }

                        count++;
                    }
```

Comment: your variables have `static` storage duration, but you're initializing them to `0` at the start of each loop (`for (num1 = 0;...`). It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish at this point though, from where I stand, there's no good reason to use `static` in your code

Comment: In the code you show here having `static` or not for your `numX` variables doesn't change anything, because e.g. `for (num1 = 0;...)` will start the loop with `num1` initialized to zero anyway.

Comment: It's difficult to see if my answer addresses your issue with out seeing how this fits into your program.

Comment: Maybe we have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.

Answer (score 5):

For `static` to work the way I think you expect it to, it needs to be declared inside a function. Then each time the function is called the `static` variable will maintain the last value it had at the end of the previous function call.

When `static` is used on a global variable it just restricts the usage of the variable to that file.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_storage_classes.htm

Answer (score -6):

static keyword is only use-able in functions.. not in loops

Comment: factually inaccurate